# How to delete the 0 before a number?

Tags: r, replace, character

I'm having the following difficulty in R: a dataframe has a column with some IDs, which are in the character format. What's the most concise way I can delete the 0s in front?

Example:

This is what I have:

```
ID <- as.character(c("001001","0001002","01003","001004","1005"))
order <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, order))
```

This is what I want:

```
ID2 <- as.character(c("1001","1002","1003","1004","1005"))
order2 <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, order))
```

I've tried replacing strings but it deletes the 0s I don't want (ex: the ID2[1] = 11).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

use `trimws` from base R

```r
trimws(c("001001","0001002","01003","001004","1005"),which = "left",whitespace = "0")
#> [1] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" "1005"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to do this if we convert to integer or numeric `class` as numeric values cannot have 0 prefix.  After the conversion, just wrap with `as.character` if we need the class to remain as `character`

```
df$ID <- as.character(as.integer(df$ID))
df$ID
#[1] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" "1005"
```

---

It could also be done in a regex way (unnecessary though)

```
df$ID <- sub("^0+", "", df$ID)
```

In the above code, we match one or more 0s (`0+`) at the start (`^`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

if the IDs have characters other than digits, an option is also to capture the digits after the prefix 0's and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured groups.  This would make sure that strings "0xyz" remains as such

```
df$ID <- sub("^0+(\\d+)$", "\\1", df$ID)
```